# Why isn't DragDrop enabled textbox accepting files?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

AllowDrop is enabled on both Form1 and textBox1. The events are enabled and start when DragDrop and DragEnter are performed. I've already tried rearranging the code so that textBox1_DragEnter is located before textBox1_DragDrop, but that doesn't work. What is wrong with this code?

```
private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo((string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));
    byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(fi.OpenText().ToString().ToCharArray());
    textBox1.Text = ba.ToString();
}

private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        string file = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        if (Path.GetExtension(file) != "dat")
        {
            s = "broken file";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to show us your "unshown" code.

Comment: I added it. Sorry.

Comment: If you have UAC turned on and you're running the program as an Administrator, you won't be able to drag and drop something from Windows Explorer onto your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the Effect property in the DragEnter event:

```
void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
  // your code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That allows it to accept data, but it doesn't show up. That's a separate problem, though. I'll work on debugging that.